# Extracting a substring from a string in python based on Delimiter

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, substring

I have an input string like:-

```
    a=1|b=2|c=3|d=4|e=5 and so on...
```

What I would like to do is extract d=4 part from a very long string of similar pattern.Is there any way to get a substring based on starting point delimter and ending point delimiter?

Such that, I can start from 'd=' and search till '|' to extract its value.Any insights would be welcome.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `regex` here :

```
>>> data = 'a=1|b=2|c=3|d=4|e=5'
>>> var = 'd'
>>> output = re.search('(?is)('+ var +'=[0-9]*)\|',data).group(1)
>>> print(output)
'd=4'
```

Or you can also use `split` which is more recommended option :

```
>>> data = 'a=1|b=2|c=3|d=4|e=5'
>>> output = data.split('|')
>>> print(output[3])
'd=4'
```

Or you can use `dic` also :

```
>>> data = 'a=1|b=2|c=3|d=4|e=5'
>>> output = dict(i.split('=') for i in data.split('|'))
{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4', 'e': '5'}
>>> output ['d']
'4'
```

Comment: `i[0]:i[2]` won't work for substrings like `'foo=123'`.

Comment: @timgeb please check !

Comment: Yeah, that works. But now you have to call `split` on `=` twice, that's why I used a `for` loop for the dictionary that stores the integers,

Comment: @timgeb absolutely, I can also use `dict()` to achieve the same, should I ?

Comment: Yes, the `dict`  constructor takes an iterable of 2-element tuples, and split on = will produce these tuples.

Comment: Hi @Mayank Jha if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a dictionary!

```
>>> s = 'a=1|b=2|c=3|d=4|e=5'
>>> dic = dict(sub.split('=') for sub in s.split('|'))
>>> dic['d']
'4'
```

If you want to store the integer values, use a `for` loop:

```
>>> s = 'a=1|b=2|c=3|d=4|e=5'
>>> dic = {}
>>> for sub in s.split('|'):
...     name, val = sub.split('=')
...     dic[name] = int(val)
... 
>>> dic['d']
4
```

Comment: I could very well be misinterpreting but, OP states that he needs it as a substring, not to access the value in some way.

Comment: Hi @Mayank Jha if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this "startswith" , specific which variable you want the value

```
 string = " a=1|b=2|c=3|d=4|e=5 "
 array = string.split("|")
 for word in array:
     if word.startswith("d"):
     print word
```