# Parse a word after repeated symbol

Tags: python, string

I have string for example:

```
gi|339906901|ref|NC_015840.1| Pygocentrus nattereri mitochondrion, complete genome >gi|338797306|dbj|AP012000.1| Pygocentrus nattereri mitochondrial DNA,
```

I want to get the string between the forth and the fifth " | " using python code .. how can i do that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting a substring from a string in python based on Delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43840717/extracting-a-substring-from-a-string-in-python-based-on-delimiter)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s.split('|')[4]
```

This code splits the string `s` on every `|` and takes the fifth element of the resulting list, between the fourth and fifth `|`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split method and use '|' as your delimiter, then grab the fifth element of the array:

```
example = your_string
example.split('|')[4]
```